# How to use Popup defined in App.xaml Resources?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a popup defined inside App.xaml resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Popup x:Key="popup">
            //some content here
        </Popup>
   </Application.Resources>
```

I want to use it in this way:

```
                    Popup popup = this.Resources["popup"] as Popup;
                    popup.IsOpen = true;
```

For some reason the popup does not show?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is, when you define the `PopUp` and its contents inside App.xaml `Resources`, you are assigning it to a visual tree different from the one displayed on your page. Setting the `IsOpen` property to true works is not enough to actually make it visible, you have to add the `PopUp` to the current visual tree.
Here comes your second problem, since the `PopUp` already has a `Parent`, you can't add it directly to your page because you would get an `InvalidOperationException`.

Here's a possible solution:

```
popup = App.Current.Resources["popup"] as Popup;
App.Current.Resources.Remove("popup");  // remove the PopUp from the Resource and thus clear his Parent property
ContentPanel.Children.Add(popup);       // add the PopUp to a container inside your page visual tree
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Beware that this way you no longer have its reference inside the Resource dictionary of your App and if you try a subsequent call to this method it will fail due to a NullReferenceException. Again, with a little bit of code, you can fix this and add the PopUp back to the Resources when you close it:

popup.IsOpen = false;                       // local reference to your PopUp stored before
ContentPanel.Children.Remove(popup);        // remove from the current visual tree
App.Current.Resources.Add("popup", popup);  // add it back to Resources

Although this code works and you can have your PopUp displayed correctly, i think it's a bit of an overkill just for a `PopUp` you can actually define inside your page and simply make it visible by changing the `IsOpen` property.